# ListView in ViewPager that don't refresh the first time (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, refresh

I have a ViewPager with 2 Fragments.

One of them with a ListView that shows the elements in a data base, and a CheckBox for every element. 
If you check the CheckBox then in my data base change a variable and I call notifyDataSetChanged(), so my fragment is refreshed. (The data base works fine and the notifyDataSetChanget() too).

The other fragment has a ListView that shows the elements of the data base that have been checked with the button, with the same features when you check the checkbox and also work fine.

Well, every fragment has his own adapter.

And I want to push the CheckBox in one of them, and that automatically change the ListView in the other fragment. This is the problem!

How I can achieve this?

I tried using both adapter in every fragment, but, the first time that the ViewPager is shown doesn't work, the time before yes... but, this is a bad app.

Thank!

Code:

Fragment 1 of the viewPager

public class FragmentEdadAntigua1Tab1 extends SherlockFragment {

```
ListView list;
AdapterListViewFragment adapter;
AdapterListViewFragmentFav adapter2;
DataBase bd;

ArrayList<RellenoListView> rellenoList;

public FragmentEdadAntigua1Tab1(AdapterListViewFragment adapter,AdapterListViewFragmentFav adapter2){
    this.adapter=adapter;
    this.adapter2=adapter2;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);

    //Background
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview_tab_1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_background_ea1); 

    getAll();
    adapter.setRellenoListView(rellenoList); 


    // Locate the ListView in fragmenttab1.xml
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_tab_1);

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
    //adapter = new AdapterListViewFragment(getActivity(),R.layout.listview_item_2,rellenoList,1);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //To allow to refresh the other fragment
    adapter.setAdapterAux(adapter2);  

    return view;
}


public void getAll(){
    RellenoListView rellenoAux;


    rellenoList = new ArrayList<RellenoListView>();


    bd = new DataBase(getActivity());
    bd.open();


    Cursor cursor=bd.getTodos(1);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            rellenoAux = new RellenoListView();

            rellenoAux.setImg(cursor.getInt(1)); /
            rellenoAux.setTitulo(cursor.getString(2));
            rellenoAux.setTiempo(cursor.getString(3));

            String fav = cursor.getString(4);
            String list = cursor.getString(5);

            if(fav.equals("0")){ /
                rellenoAux.setSelectedFav(false);
            }else{
                rellenoAux.setSelectedFav(true);                
            }
            if(list.equals("0")){ 
                rellenoAux.setSelectedList(false);
            }else{
                rellenoAux.setSelectedList(true);                   
            }

            rellenoAux.setUrl(cursor.getString(6));

            rellenoList.add(rellenoAux);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    bd.close();    
}
```

}

Fragment 2 of the viewPager

public class FragmentEdadAntigua1Tab2 extends SherlockFragment{

```
ArrayList<RellenoListView> favList;
DataBase bd;
ListView list;
AdapterListViewFragmentFav adapter;
AdapterListViewFragment adapter2;

public FragmentEdadAntigua1Tab2(AdapterListViewFragmentFav adapter, AdapterListViewFragment adapter2){
    this.adapter=adapter;
    this.adapter2=adapter2;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view;      

    favList = new ArrayList<RellenoListView>();

    //Get only the favourites
    getFav();


    if(favList.isEmpty()){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_2_sin, container, false);


        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview_tab_2);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_background_ea1); 

    }else{ 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_2_con, container, false);


        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview_tab_2);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_background_ea1); 

        // Locate the ListView in fragmenttab1.xml
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_tab_2);

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        //adapter = new AdapterListViewFragmentFav(getActivity(),R.layout.listview_item_2,favList,1); 

        adapter.setRellenoListView(favList);  

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //To allow to refresh the other fragment
        adapter.setAdapterAux(adapter2);


    }

    return view;
}



public void getFav(){
    RellenoListView rellenoAux;

    bd = new DataBase(getActivity());                       
    bd.open();



    Cursor cursor=bd.getTodos(1);   

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
               String fav = cursor.getString(4);    

               if(fav.equals("1")){ 
                    rellenoAux = new RellenoListView(); 

                    rellenoAux.setImg(cursor.getInt(1)); 
                    rellenoAux.setTitulo(cursor.getString(2));
                    rellenoAux.setTiempo(cursor.getString(3));

                    rellenoAux.setSelectedFav(true);  

                    String list = cursor.getString(5);
                    if(list.equals("0")){ 
                        rellenoAux.setSelectedList(false);
                    }else{
                        rellenoAux.setSelectedList(true);                   
                    }

                    rellenoAux.setUrl(cursor.getString(6));


                    favList.add(rellenoAux);
                }

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

     }


     bd.close();    

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to provide the exact solution without viewing your code. But one thing you can do is to create a thread which has an infinite loop running in some interval (maybe 5 secs) and refresh the listView.

Code may look something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                return;
            }
            usersList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Ok, now I also show the code.  The problem I think is in the line: adapter.setAdapterAux(adapter2);